# Laravel before making view event

Tags: php, events, laravel, view, frameworks

Is there a way to handle a 'before make view' event for a specific controller in Laravel ? 
I mean before generating a view I want to do a common thing for each action of a specific controller to be DRY.
Thank you.

Comment: What is it that you want to do for each action?

Comment: I want to do a ->with('sectionTitle', $this->sectionTitle);
*$sectionTitle is a title of the page of a section in my Backend Application that changes from action to action of my Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setupLayout` method. If you're using the `BaseController` class that comes with a default laravel installation. It is already defined and you can extend or override it.

**BaseController** (if you're using it and want to do it for every controller extending from it)

```
protected function setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }

    if(isset($this->sectionTitle)){ // just to be sure
        View::share('sectionTitle', $this->sectionTitle);
    }
}
```

**One of your Controllers**

```
protected function setupLayout()
{    
    if(isset($this->sectionTitle)){ // just to be sure
        View::share('sectionTitle', $this->sectionTitle);
    }
    parent::setupLayout(); // add this if you're extending from a controller that has implemented the setupLayout() function
}
```

Comment: Meanwhile this is the most accurate, straight to the point and honors MVP I still would like to know how one can use events with Views within Controllers. @lukasgeiter is this something you can probably unpack for me?